# ReactJS got net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs

I'm creating a react application with create-react-app and axios,
and trying to get json response data from json-server. But it's not working.
I'm using `react-scripts start`.

Both the react app and json-server are running on the same docker container.
The react app is using 3000 port, and the json-server is using 8888 port.

I can get data from json-server using curl command like this `curl -X GET localhost:8888/user`.
But the react app can't connect to the json-server.

Versions...

- react: 16.13.1
- react-scripts: 3.4.1
- axios: 0.19.2
- json-server: 0.16.1
- Docker: 19.03.8

Below are my codes and error messages.

**ReactJS Code**

```
import axios from 'axios'

const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8888',
  timeout: 1000,
})

const getAll = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await client.get('/user')
    const users = res.data.users
    return users
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

**json-server code**

```
const jsonServer = require('json-server')
const server = jsonServer.create()
const router = jsonServer.router('./src/mock/db.json')

router.render = (req, res) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  if (req.url.match(/user/)) {
    if (req.route.path === '/:id') {
      res.jsonp({
        message: 'mock server...',
        user: res.locals.data,
      })
    } else {
      res.jsonp({
        message: 'mock server...',
        users: res.locals.data,
      })
    }
  }
}

server.use(router)
server.listen(8888, 'localhost', () => {
  console.log('JSON server is running...')
})
```

**Error messages**

```
xhr.js:178 GET http://localhost:8888/user net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:178
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:12
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:52
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:61
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:76
wrap @ bind.js:9
getAll @ user.js:5
(anonymous) @ PersonalCards.js:9
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:19731
commitPassiveHookEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19769
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:188
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:237
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:292
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:22853
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:653
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11039
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:22820
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:22699
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:597
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:552
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:164
```

Please tell me solutions to solve this problem...

Comment: Probably a cors error, you can use a [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) in development.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but a proxy doesn't work... I added `"proxy": "http://localhost:8888"` to package.json and restarted the react app. But I got the same error.